# Serial data problem in orange Pi zero serial port python

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, rfid, orange-pi

I am reading RFID data from RFID card using a serial port. The card is sending data continuously.

```
serial_port = serial.Serial(
    port="/dev/ttyS2",
    timeout=2,
    baudrate=38400,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
)
while True:
    cmdRet=serial_port.read(6)
    print("Raw1 = "+str(cmdRet))
```

If I use the USB to serial converter and connect it to orange PI it is reading the data correctly. According to the documentation also when it does not detect RFID card it continuously sends in ASCII `U\r\n` but if I connect the UART of orange PI it reads incorrect data like when there is no RFID card it reads `\x00\xbdUy=`

whereas `\x00` is for NULL character and `0xbd` is even not a valid `utf-8` character.

I have connected common groud also and I am not sure what the problem is. Can anyone guide me?

I have to use UART of orange PI in the final product.

Comment: You need to clearly identify these *"serial ports"* that you are trying to use.  Are you confusing RS-232 ports with serial (UART) TTL ports?

Comment: I think you are right. TTL should be connected with TTL and RS-232 with RS-232.

Answer (score 0):

- Because it is reading bytes from the serial port.
- Try to decode it, such as `***.decode("utf-8")` .

Comment: it is not about decoding. I used this decoding with USB to serial convertor and that is reading perfect, it even gives error when I use decode in UART. Error is `print("Raw1 = "+cmdRet.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 0: invalid start byte`